# Targeting older mobile devices in 2019

Tags: android, ios

Something doesn't add up:

According to [Google Play’s target API level requirements](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk) new apps for Android as of June 2019 cannot target Android versions below 8. Starting with August 2019, nothing below version 9.

Yet, according to [Distribution dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) the 9's version devices share is just a bit above 10% while 9 and 8 combined get you to about 30%.

Am I correct to deduce that anyone thinking of creating a new app today (June 2019)

1. can only reach 30% of his Android audience (via Play Store) and
2. if s/he doesn't make it before August, only 10% of the whole Android users can be reached?

Apple has a similarly sounding page [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03202019a), but: 1. it mentions iOS 12 share being above 80% and 2. I don't think *built using iOS 12.1 SDK or later* really means *targeting iOS 12.1 and above*.

Current Xcode still lets you target iOS 8.0 (do they still accept it into the App Store?) which still happily runs on 2011 iPhone 4S despite its minuscule market share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `targetSdkVersion` restriction was introduced to prevent app developers from using old apis like permissions to bypass runtime permissions.
An app targeting older api version was always allowed all required permissions at installation time. With the introduction of  run time permissions, user has a better understanding and control of permissions in app. 
The `minSdkVersion` is the one which actually affects from which version of Android your app runs. 
API Level 21 would do good as it has near to 85% coverage of devices.

Comment: Things didn't add up for a reason. Thank you for adding the insight on targetSdkVersion restriction.

Comment: Happy to help :D

Answer (score 0):

The restrictions that the Play Store imposes is on `targetSdkVersion`. You are confusing that with `minSdkVersion`. `minSdkVersion` controls how old of an Android device can run the code, and this is not affected by the Play Store restrictions.

Comment: The same answer applies to iOS. An app can be built for iOS 12 and be deployable at least as far down as iOS 8. The current beta of Xcode 11 can increase the spread to iOS 13 without removing iOS 8.