# Will minSdkVersion 21 allow only Android >= 5 users to download app from store?

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

In my react native android project I want to set limit to Android version >= 5.
In `build.gradle` I set `minSdkVersion 21`.
Is this setting enough and users that have android < 5 will not be able to get it from store?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it will prevent installs.

Check this out [image]

this is the distribution of api levels as per google, if you set the `minSdkLevel` it will restrict users from installing the app, if they do not have a device with that particular API level. realistically you are only taking the app away from a small margin of users, as you can see from the distribution

Answer (score 3):

Yes, minimumSdk determines the lowest api level on which it works. The targetSdkVersion restriction was introduced to prevent app developers from using old apis like permissions to bypass runtime permissions. An app targeting older api version was always allowed all required permissions at installation time. With the introduction of run time permissions, user has a better understanding and control of permissions in app. The minSdkVersion is the one which actually affects from which version of Android your app runs. API Level 21 would do good as it has near to 85% coverage of devices.
[Targeting older mobile devices in 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704047/targeting-older-mobile-devices-in-2019/56704368#56704368)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, refer the Android version-codename-api @ https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers